# How can I force programatically JVM to reread OS key mappings?

Tags: java, keyboard

When JVM starts, It loads current OS keysym mappings for a specific key. When I change dinamically OS key mappings with "xmodmap", JVM can't recognize the change, and still use's old keysyms.
How can I force programatically JVM to reread OS key mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle: Troubleshooting guide for java desktop technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/awt-138016.html)

> On UNIX systems that support dynamic keyboard changes, a running Java application does not recognize such a change. For instance, changing the keyboard from US to German does not change the keyboard mapping. Although the X server detects the change and sends out a MappingNotify event to interested clients, AWT does not refresh its notion of the keycode-keysym mapping.

Seems the answer is: not.